# Existe alguma vantagem em reunir todos os ícones de um site em uma única imagem?

Tags: html, imagem

Vejo na maioria dos grandes sites que os ícones utilizados estão agrupados em apenas uma imagem, o que acarreta no download de apenas um arquivo por parte do usuário. Existe algum benefício em ganhos de velocidade ou é apenas uma questão de organização?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A questão aqui é diminuir a quantidade de requisições que o navegador faz ao servidor e, portanto, otimizar o tempo de carregamento da página e diminuir o tempo de resposta ao usuário.

## Desempenho

Isso melhora o desempenho porque os navegadores limitam a quantidade de *downloads* simultâneos, então o carregamento de muitas imagens seria enfileirado um após o outro. Pense num gerenciador de *downloads* com 100 itens na fila e um limite de apenas 3 *downloads* ao mesmo tempo.

Considere o gráfico gerado em uma [pesquisa do Yahoo!](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/28/performance-research-part-1/):

[image: Tempo de download dos itens de uma página]

Baseando-se no Princípio de Preto (80-20), eles chegaram a uma aproximação de que 80% do tempo gasto no carregamento de uma página era gasto por imagens. Veja a tabela abaixo, retirada do mesmo artigo, com a medida de outros sites:

[image: Tempo de carregamento do HTML e de outros itens]

Note que scripts e estilos também podem causar o mesmo efeito, por isso quem se preocupa em reunir as imagens em uma geralmente também vai reunir todos os scripts e estilos em arquivos unificados e minificados.

E mesmo que todas as imagens e outros itens estáticos estejam em *cache*, o navegador ainda pode verificar com certa frequência, a depender do cabeçalho HTTP do site, se houve modificação. Para isso, ele terá que fazer requisições adicionais.

## Escalabilidade

Outro fator que sites grandes consideram é a escalabilidade. Eles não querem que seu navegador faça dezenas ou centenas de pequenas requisições porque isso diminui a quantidade de pessoas que eles conseguem atender ao mesmo tempo.

## Custos com CDN

A quantidade de acessos é também uma preocupação adicional em sites grandes que usam CDN, pois eles pagam por requisição. Uma CDN é como um *cache* externo à sua empresa responsável por entregar conteúdo estático de forma rápida e confiável. O problema é que cada acesso ao CDN irá lhe custar alguns centavos, então é melhor 1 do que 100 acessos acesso por usuário. O Facebook, por exemplo, [criou um sistema chamado *Haystack*](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919) par armazenar suas bilhões de imagens e uma das principais preocupações era diminuir o uso do CND para distribuir as imagens.

## Efeitos colaterais

Em contrapartida, fazer a junção de imagens, scripts e estilos aumenta a complexidade e os problemas em potencial no *deploy* de uma aplicação. Muitas otimizações específicas tem esse tipo de efeito.

Li alguns relatos de que o *zoom* de alguns navegadores pode degradar a solução com *sprites*, mas pode ser que seja apenas uma implementação ruim.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, existe também a vantagem visual para o site, quando se altera o fundo de um elemento de uma imagem para outra (botões e sliders) o fundo do elemento ficará vazio até a nova imagem ser carregada, é possível solucionar isso pré-carregando as imagens com Javascript, mas as sprites poupam o trabalho. Outro fator é o de armazenamento onde a junção de muitos arquivos minúsculos pode acabar fazendo com que eles ocupem mais do que realmente deveriam.

Comment: Em OpenGL pelo menos, usar uma `sprite` ao invés de várias texturas separadas é mais eficiente também (carrega mais rápido, alterna entre as imagens mais rápido, economiza memória). Se o navegador aproveitar a GPU, provavelmente essa regra é válida também.

Comment: Um dos efeitos colaterais é aumentar a paleta de cores da imagem como um todo, caso os icones nao compartilhem muitas cores semelhantes. Quando é esse o caso, tem-se que calcular se compensa 2 sets de icone ou mais separados (avaliando custo da requisição http vs. tamanho economizado com overhead da paleta).

Comment: @Cahe Interessante. Este é mesmo um problema comum.

Comment: @LucasNunes Eu cheguei a pensar nisso e realmente deve ser melhor do ponto de vista de uso de memória e na renderização, afinal qualquer *engine* decente teria que reusar o mesmo ponteiro da imagem. O problema é que na prática *pode* não ser tão eficiente por causa do *overhead* de processamento do CSS que necessário para fazer o *clip* da imagem. Bem, é apenas uma ideia. Você tem alguma referência sobre essa questão? Alguém que chegou a testar essa questão na prática?

Comment: @Bacco Não sou especialista em imagens. O tamanho da paleta faz o tamanho da imagem aumentar proporcionalmente? Eu sei que em GIF isso é um problema pois as cores da paleta são limitadas e o resultado de muitos ícones ficaria, no mínimo, deteriorado. Formatos como PNG que usam cores RGBA sofrem de problemas au usar mais ou menos cores?

Comment: @utluiz Infelizmente eu não achei um benchmark que relacione os dois. Ou acho que `sprites` no navegador ou em opengl, agora a união dos dois não. Apesar disso, a maioria dos benchmark de navegadores que vi usam `sprites` (ex: fishbowl).

Comment: @utluiz PNG24/32 é RRGGBB(AA) por pixel, então o tamanho nao depende das cores (a não ser no que diz respeito à compressão). O PNG8, por sua vez, ja é baseado em paleta, então ele se comporta como o GIF (a paleta pode ter de 2 a 256 cores, e o número de bits por pixel é proporcional ao tamanho da paleta). Quanto mais bits precisar por cor, maior fica o arquivo. Justamente como no GIF, se você tiver cores variadas, vai precisar de uma paleta maior para acomodar todas sem detonar o visual.

Answer (score 5):

Essa prática de reunir as imagens em uma só é chamado de `sprite`.

A vantagem é que você economiza requisições ao servidor. Para sites pequenos isso não faz muita diferença, mas para grandes sites, cujo numero de acessos é muito alto, faz.

Ou seja, ao invés de fazer 10 requisições ao servidor para carregar vários icozinhos, você pode fazer uma só e carregar todos os ícones de uma vez só.

Consequentemente, tendo um servidor menos ocupado, você terá um site que responderá melhor aos usuários.

**Exemplo:**
O próprio SO usa `sprites`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Pra complementar a respostas dos parceiros, você pode utilizar essa ferramenta aqui --> http://www.spritecow.com/ pra te ajudar a fazer um sprite se estiver com dificuldade, é bem fácil, é só selecionar a região da imagem que contêm um certo ícone ou alguma figura, e ela te gera uma classe css com a respectiva posição que por fim é só chamar essa classe la no html e está feito.

Nota: Dependendo do elemento em que você atribuir essa classe, você terá que colocar um display: block nela (no case se você tentar atribuir a um elemento inline).

Abraço.